# Publish via VS vs dotnet.exe publish why is the second faster

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have a solution with many projects, when it's time to publish we usually go one by one and publish it on VS. This was consuming a lot of time so we tried to publish it via "dotnet.exe publish" and it was a massive improvement in publish times for each project.

This leaves me with some questions that the internet has been unable to answer me so far:

- Is the command skipping any steps?
- Are the published projects different in any way?
- Why is it faster?

Here are both configurations I'm using:

VS Publish Profile:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>DEV</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <PrecompileBeforePublish>True</PrecompileBeforePublish>
    <EnableUpdateable>True</EnableUpdateable>
    <DebugSymbols>True</DebugSymbols>
    <Optimize>False</Optimize>
    <UseMerge>True</UseMerge>
    <WDPMergeOption>MergeAllOutputsToASingleAssembly</WDPMergeOption>
    <SingleAssemblyName>_DEV</SingleAssemblyName>
    <DeleteAppCodeCompiledFiles>True</DeleteAppCodeCompiledFiles>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>True</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>C:\Inetpub\Dev</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
</PropertyGroup>
```

PowerShell:

```
dotnet.exe publish "C:\Projects\ProjectFolder\Project\Project.csproj" --configuration "DEV" --framework netcoreapp2.0 --force --output "C:\Inetpub\Dev"
```